# How to enable long double in Intel ICC

Tags: c++, c, intel, icc, long-double

I'm on MacOS, and am following the guide [Using the Intel® Math Library](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/optimization-and-programming-guide/intel-math-library/using-the-intel-math-library.html) to implement the first example:

```c
// real_math.c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <mathimf.h>

int main() {
 float fp32bits;
 double fp64bits;
 long double fp80bits;
 long double pi_by_four = 3.141592653589793238/4.0;

// pi/4 radians is about 45 degrees
 fp32bits = (float) pi_by_four; // float approximation to pi/4
 fp64bits = (double) pi_by_four; // double approximation to pi/4
 fp80bits = pi_by_four; // long double (extended) approximation to pi/4

// The sin(pi/4) is known to be 1/sqrt(2) or approximately .7071067 
 printf("When x = %8.8f, sinf(x) = %8.8f \n", fp32bits, sinf(fp32bits));
 printf("When x = %16.16f, sin(x) = %16.16f \n", fp64bits, sin(fp64bits));
 printf("When x = %20.20Lf, sinl(x) = %20.20Lf \n", fp80bits, sinl(fp80bits));

 return 0; 
}
```

As directed in the guide, I compile with:

```sh
icc real_math.c
```

When I execute, I get:

```
When x = 0.78539819, sinf(x) = 0.70710677 
When x = 0.7853981633974483, sin(x) = 0.7071067811865475 
When x = 0.78539816339744830952, sinl(x) = 0.00000000000000000000
```

**I've searched wide and far, and all examples seem to show that this should be trivial. What am I missing?**

I tried to pass `-long_double` to `icc`, but nothing changes.

Comment: Are you looking for an option to make `sizeof(long double) > 8`, using x87 80-bit?  That should already be the case on GNU/Linux targets, but not by default in the Windows ABI where long-double = double.

Comment: @PeterCordes • the OP is on MacOS, which is neither a GNU/Linux target nor a Windows ABI target.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Presumably `sinl` is getting an all-zero input, or a small integer that represent an 80-bit float close to zero, because the caller disagrees with the callee about where the arg should be passed.  Note the all-zero output, which is not mathematically correct, and not what you get for a working compiler like x86-64 GCC targeting Linux with a normal `math.h` - https://godbolt.org/z/z4hjTc

Comment: Thank you for the godbolt link @PeterCordes, I wasn't aware of this tool. I've set it to replicate my environment, and can see correct output. But when I try this on my local machine, I get 0 for sinl

Comment: @Eljay: Ah right.  Same ABI as Linux, x86-64 System V.  So `long double` is the 80-bit x87 type.  Perhaps Intel's library is using asm functions written for a different ABI, where `long double` = `double` and is passed / returned in XMM0 instead of arg on the stack, ret in `st(0)`.  But if the caller tried to `fstp` the return value from `st0` (x87 register), when the x87 register stack was empty, that would store a `-nan` to memory, not `0`.  (My earlier comment about a zero *input* to sinl was ignoring the fact that a calling-convention mismatch would be a problem for return values)

Comment: @SevaSafris: Can you double-check `sizeof(long double)` in your local `icc`?  Note that Godbolt's compilers are set up to target GNU/Linux, not MacOS.  That should work the same, but possibly not.  Also, you could single-step into the `sinl` library function and see if the asm is using x87 instructions or SSE2 / AVX.

Comment: Just in passing, note that `3.141592653589793238` and `4.0` are both doubles, so the value stored in `pi_by_four` has the precision of a double. To make them long doubles, add a `L`: `3.141592653589793238L` and `4.0L`. (You can also use lower-case l, but nobody does that, because it can look too much like a 1).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. This problem was caused by an error on my part due to the omission of 1 character: `L`. Specifically, somehow in my own code on my computer I had this:

```c
 printf("When x = %20.20Lf, sinl(x) = %20.20f \n", fp80bits, sinl(fp80bits));
```

and the correct code is this (note `%20.20f` vs `%20.20Lf`):

```c
 printf("When x = %20.20Lf, sinl(x) = %20.20Lf \n", fp80bits, sinl(fp80bits));
```

I'm not even sure how this could have happened, but this was the root cause.

Thank you everyone for your quick answers, and thanks @PeterCordes for linking me to **godbolt**.

Comment: In future, checking with a debugger (maybe using a tmp var) would have let you see you were getting a result from `sinl`, separate from printf printing it.  Also `%f` (unlike `%g`) doesn't distinguish between 0.0 and very tiny floats, so doesn't rule out some kinds of calling-convention mismatches.